# pbgtest, pwartest and pbltest yields different results

Tags: r, econometrics, panel-data, autocorrelation, intraclass-correlation

I am doing a econometrics assignments that asks me to evaluate the best panel data models for a production function.

I have the following R code:

```
data <- read_dta("prodfn_data_5_1.dta")


# Create panel data object
pdata <- pdata.frame(data, index = c("ivar", "tvar"));pdata

form = y ~ l + k
##########################
### Fixed effect model ###
##########################

# Estimate production function using fixed effects model
model_fe <- plm(form, data = pdata, model = "within", effect = "individual"); summary(model_fe)

# Run specification tests
bptest(model_fe)  # Breusch-Pagan test for heteroscedasticity
## test fails to reject heteroskedasticity


pwartest(model_fe, cluster = "time") # Wooldridge test for correlation
pwartest(model_fe, cluster = "group") # Wooldridge test for correlation

pbgtest()


cov_fe <- vcovHC(model_fe, method = "arellano", cluster = "group")

coeftest(model_fe, vcov. = cov_fe)
#################################
### Pooled fixed effect model ###
#################################

model_pl <- plm(y ~ l + k, data = pdata, model = "pooling"); summary(model_pl)

phtest(model_fe, model_pl, vcov = cov_fe, effect)  # Poolability test for fixed effect

## this Hausman test shows that the pooled model is inconsistent

###########################
### Random effect model ###
###########################

model_re <- plm(y ~ l + k, data = pdata, model = "random"); summary(model_re)

pbltest(model_re)

phtest(model_fe, model_re)
```

Now, the interesting thing that I cannot understand why happens is that the command `pbgtest()` always delivers different results than `pwartest()` and `pbltest()`. They should test the same exact thing(serial correlation), but while pbgtest almost always rejects the H0, the other two fail to reject it.

Why does this happen?
Which test should I trust?